# Экранирование специальных символов

Tags: php

После экранирования спец. символов не работает unserialize. Не работает он 100% из-за экранирования. Экранировал с помощью `mysql_real_escape_string`. Без экранирования в БД не заносится. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно заэкранировать спецсимволы?

Comment: Забыть про `serialize` и юзать `json_*`, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text); /* спецсимволы */
$text = stripslashes($text); /* обратные слэши*/
```